# Bash alias with piping

Tags: bash, alias

I'm not exactly sure what I'm doing wrong with this one. I'm trying to run the command

```
alias localip='ip -4 -o addr show eth0 | egrep -o '([[:digit:]]{1,3}\.){3}[[:digit:]]{1,3}' | head -n 1'
```

If I run the command

```
ip -4 -o addr show eth0 | egrep -o '([[:digit:]]{1,3}\.){3}[[:digit:]]{1,3}' | head -n 1
```

I get the result I expect, however, when trying to create an alias with the command, I get

> -bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('

Any help would be appreciated. TIA.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You're nesting single quotes within single quotes. That doesn't work.

Try using `"`double quotes`"` in the inner expression.

Comment: Or escaped single quotes.

Comment: Thank you soooo much. I knew it was something simple, I was just looking at it for too long.

Comment: You cannot escape single quotes inside a single quoted string: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Single-Quotes

Answer (score 8):

I found it a much cleaner solution to just create a function and name your alias after the function, like this:

```
alias localip=GetLocalIP

function GetLocalIP()
{
   ip -4 -o addr show eth0 | egrep -o '([[:digit:]]{1,3}\.){3}[[:digit:]]{1,3}' | head -n 1
}
```

Comment: What's the advantage of creating an alias to a function, rather than just naming the function `localip`? Also, the `function` keyword breaks compatibility with other shells. I'd suggest just using `localip() { ...`

Comment: @TomFenech Your suggestion works in general. It's just a personal style that works for me: All my functions start with a verb, so that it makes sense in code (reused elsewhere). . However, that style slows me down when it comes to CLI typing. So alias comes as a compromise. Verbosity like the `function` keyword helps me define code parsers or generators later.

Comment: @tom-fenech - I'm going to poke around in some of the other shells I tend to use, but out of curiosity, what are some of the shells that are incompatible?

Comment: @AFK see [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/73750/difference-between-function-foo-and-foo) for a thorough discussion on that topic.